# Need to copy OTP

Tags: c#

My use case is that my user has an outlook account and I am doing automation so when a person login a 2FA is required,

so I need to copy the OTP and paste it into my application

I m writing code in c#, is there any way to connect to outlook?

my code is below but nothing showing in console

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace new project
{
  internal class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
      NameSpace outlookNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
      MAPIFolder inbox = outlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
      Items items = inbox.Items;
      foreach(object item in items)
      {
        if (item is MailItem mailItem)
        {
          if (mailItem.Subject.Contains("One-Time Password for Your Account")) 
          {
            string body = mailItem.Body;
            int startIndex = body.IndexOf("OTP:") + 4;
            int length = 6;
            string otp = body.Substring(startIndex, length);

            Console.WriteLine("OTP: " + otp);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to copy the OTP and paste it into my application

Comment: Sounds sketchy.

Comment: The whole point of two factor authentication is that it involves user interaction, by doing so it notifies the legitimate user if an unauthorised user is attempting to access their account. Automating this step would invalidate the whole point of implementing it.